# why is angular universal server returning plain php code back from api

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, angular, angular-universal

I've been working on an angular project for a couple of months, which I implemented universal (SSR) into it. this works perfectly fine on my pc (although I didn't direct to port 4000 internally since there's no special domain other than localhost:4000).

I deployed this project to a VPS server (centos os with a cyber panel), which after installing a node on the server, I had to direct incoming requests on ports 80 and 443 to the universal server internally using Nginx and this works perfectly well. I have tried all I can to make this node server run on HTTPS with SSL, all to no avail, and all API calls return plain texts (I use PHP for backend with MySQL) this project is already live and in use.

my cyber panel server already has PHP and MySql, I can connect to my database by placing the database connection file into any folder in the public_html folder of my site, everything functions perfectly (including the database) and there's SSL installed on it.

but after starting the server file using `pm2 start server.js` and directing the request to the node server the site just becomes an empty site, the PHP files are being reached but they are all returned as plain text. I don't really know if the node server has to be configured again to accept PHP.

after installing and starting nginx the somewhere inside the nginx.conf file
`server { listen 80; listen 443 ssl; ssl_key: path/to/ssl/sert ssl_csr: pat/to/ssl/.csr location / { proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:4000;// this is the node server running internally } }`

Comment: Have you set up the web server to handle PHP? It's hard to know what _actually_ is going on when all we have is a wall of text. Can you please edit the question and include some facts about the environment? Where is the PHP files located? How are you calling the PHP files (which us all the relevant code etc)

Comment: Show how you did your redirection. You should not redirect API traffic and angular universal